# Rails active record relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This follows from this question ([How can I have two columns in one table point to the same column in another with ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879014/how-can-i-have-two-columns-in-one-table-point-to-the-same-column-in-another-with)) but there is a slightly different nuance.

I have a model `Order`, which has three columns that point to the same table `Estimate`: `estimate_id`, `finalized_estimate_id`, `cost_price_estimate_id`.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :estimate
  belongs_to :finalized_estimate, class_name: "Estimate", optional: true
  belongs_to :cost_price_estimate, class_name: "Estimate", optional: true
end
```

What would the estimate class look like? And secondly could an estimate know which column it is from? I.e. will/can an estimate model know it is a `finalized_estimate`, `cost_price_estimate` or just an `estimate`?

(Estimate will always only `have_one` order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do following,

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :estimate # default foreign_key is estimate_id
  belongs_to :finalized_estimate, class_name: "Estimate", foreign_key: 'finalized_estimate_id', optional: true
  belongs_to :cost_price_estimate, class_name: "Estimate", foreign_key: 'cost_price_estimate_id', optional: true
end
```

Rest is fine. :)

*Explaination:*

Rails prefer **convention over configuration(COC)** i.e.

When you write `finalized_estimate`, It looks for `FinalizedEstimate` model instead of `Estimate` by convention and search for `finalized_estimate_id`, So you have to provide it explicitly.

For `belongs_to :estimate`, It gets class `Estimate` & foreign_key `estimate_id` implicitly.

In other side,

```
class Estimate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :finalized_order, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: 'finalized_estimate_id'
  has_many :cost_price_order, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: 'cost_price_estimate_id'
end
```

Here primary key is always present at `orders` table as `id`

Comment: Thanks ray, 

My understanding is that the default foreign key is set according to the name. So `:finalized_estimate` will become `finalized_estimate_id `. Not sure if this changes anything in the class.

My main concern though is when you have an estimate object, how it would know which "type" of estimate it is..

Comment: @Toma, I added explanation which will clear your idea. Upvote & accept answers if it is satisfactory :)

Comment: `When you write finalized_estimate, It looks for FinalizedEstimate model instead of Estimate by convention and search for finalized_estimate_id, So you have to provide it explicitly.` => this is solved by the piece of code `class_name: "Estimate"` which was there originally 


can you expand the explanation in the other direction, I want know if `Estimate.order` can work

Comment: @Toma It will be same case for has_one also.